# Example of Stone space such that ...

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra

Suppose $X$ is a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space and $F_1,F_2,F_3$ three finite subsets of $X$.

I would like to know if $F_1 \cap F_2 \cap F_3 = \emptyset$ implies that there exists clopen sets $O_1, O_2, O_3$ such that $F_i \subseteq O_i$ and $O_1 \cap O_2 \cap O_3 = \emptyset$ ?

It seems false but I lack counterexample.

Edit : To find a counterexample, I think that a not discrete totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space which admits a finite clopen set should work (but I'm not still sure why and I'm not sure counterexamples exist).

Comment: You can separate all of the points in the finite sets and choose all of the separating open sets to be clopen and disjoint. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you give me an example for $F_1 = \lbrace x,y \rbrace$, $F_2 = \lbrace x,z \rbrace$ and $F_3 = \lbrace y,z \rbrace$ ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My response does not answer the question in the OP. My response assumes that the finite sets are pairwise disjoint.

First you need to know the definition of the  inductive dimension.

**Definition** Given a regular space $X$, the small inductive dimension $ind(X)$ is defined in the following way:

**(a)** $ind(X)=-1$ if and only if $X=\emptyset$

**(b)** For $n\geq 0$, $ind(X)\leq n$ if and only if for every $x\in X$ and every open neighbourhood $U\subseteq X$ of $x$ there is another open neighbourhood $V\subseteq X$ such that $x\in V\subseteq U$ and $ind(\partial V)\leq n-1$.

**(c)** $ind(X)=n$ if $ind(X)\leq n$ and $ind(X)\leq n-1$ does not hold.

**(d)** $ind(X)=\infty$ if $ind(X)\leq n$ does not hold for any $n$.

What is relevant for you is that $ind(X)=0$ if and only if every point has a neighbourhood basis of sets with empty boundaries, that is clopen sets.

The important fact you need is this:

**Proposition:** If a compact Hausdorff space $X$ is totally disconnected, then $ind(X)=0$.

This proposition appears in Nagami's "*Dimension Theory*".

Now let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space that is totally disconnected. Let

$$F_{1}=\{x_{1},\ldots,X_{n}\}$$

$$F_{2}=\{y_{1},\ldots,y_{m}\}$$

$$F_{3}=\{z_{1},\ldots,z_{l}\}$$

These are closed compact sets in a compact Hausdorff space, so there are disjoint open sets $U_{1},U_{2}$ and $U_{3}$ such that $F_{i}\subseteq U_{i}$. Now, within a particular $U_{i}$, say $U_{1}$, you can find disjoint open sets $W_{1},\ldots, W_{n}$ such that $x_{i}\in W_{i}$. Because $ind(X)=0$ you can then pass to clopen sets $V_{1},\ldots,V_{n}$ such that $x_{i}\in V_{i}\subseteq W_{i}$. Then define $V=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}V_{i}$. This is an open set containing $F_{1}$ and because the closures of the $V_{i}$ are all disjoint we have:

$$\partial V=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\partial V_{i}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\emptyset=\emptyset$$

Thus $V$ is clopen and disjoint from $U_{2}$ and $U_{3}$. Repeat this process for $U_{2}$ and $U_{3}$ to get two more clopen sets.

Comment: I understand that if $F_1 \cap F_2 = F_1 \cap F_3 = F_2 = F_3 = \emptyset$,  there exist disjoints  clopen sets which answer my question. But what happen if $F_1 \cap F_2 \neq \emptyset$, $F_1 \cap F_3 \neq \emptyset$, $F_2 \cap F_3 \neq \emptyset$ but $F_1 \cap F_2 \cap F_3 = \emptyset$ ? How do you find the disjoint open sets $U_1, U_2$ and $U_3$ ? (and subsenquently, the disjoint clopen sets).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question, my apologies. In the case your speaking of I'm not sure.

Comment: Not a problem, in the beginning I misunderstood the problem in the same way.